# How to clear a cluttered workspace in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, erase

In the [Pharo MOOC](https://mooc.pharo.org/) there is a proposed challenge (section 2.15.2) that consists in taking a email address and getting the associated gravatar image, as a Morph object. I was able to do it, by running the following code in the playground:

```
| url email |
email := 'stephane.ducasse@inria.fr'.
url := 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/', (MD5 hashMessage: email) hex asString , '.jpg'.
(ZnEasy getJpeg: url) asMorph openInHand.
```

Now the problem is, I could not figure out how to properly clean my workspace of all the objects downloaded:

[image]

As you can see, now I have the image from the url (from a previous botched attempt where I did url asMorph openInHand without getting the jpg with ZnEasy first), and several lighthouse images (as every time I open the inspector a new one is generated).

I say properly clean because you can just exit Pharo without saving, and then open it again to have a clean workspace, but this is probably not ideal.

So far I tried to inspect the created objects, seeing they are instances of ImageMorph. Then in the associated methods I searched something including "erase", "del", "delete" or "clear", but could not find anything similar. These were the available methods for ImageMorph:

```
{ImageMorph>>#prepareForRotating. 
ImageMorph>>#grabFromScreen. 
ImageMorph>>#forwardDirection:. 
ImageMorph>>#adoptPaneColor:. 
ImageMorph>>#drawOnAthensCanvas:. 
ImageMorph>>#extent:. 
ImageMorph>>#setOptimalResizing. 
ImageMorph>>#form:. 
ImageMorph>>#shouldFlex. 
ImageMorph>>#forwardDirection. 
ImageMorph>>#resize:. 
ImageMorph>>#areasRemainingToFill:. 
ImageMorph>>#heading. 
ImageMorph>>#imageExport. 
ImageMorph>>#defaultImage. 
ImageMorph>>#rotationDegrees. 
ImageMorph>>#borderStyle:. 
ImageMorph>>#opacityString. 
ImageMorph>>#setDirectionFrom:. 
ImageMorph>>#rotationDegrees:. 
ImageMorph>>#borderWidth:. 
ImageMorph>>#isOpaque. 
ImageMorph>>#image:. 
ImageMorph>>#readFromFile. 
ImageMorph>>#drawOn:. 
ImageMorph>>#basicExtent:. 
ImageMorph>>#form. 
ImageMorph>>#withSnapshotBorder. 
ImageMorph>>#wantsRecolorHandle. 
ImageMorph>>#changeOpacity. 
ImageMorph>>#initialize. 
ImageMorph>>#addCustomMenuItems:hand:. 
ImageMorph>>#isOpaque:. 
ImageMorph>>#releaseCachedState. 
ImageMorph>>#color:}
```

I also tried to execute garbageCollect, and just click the images and press Delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After opening them in the hand, you have positioned them in the world. If you inspect the world, you'll see there are a number of ImageMorphs. You want to exclude the Pharo logo. If you inspect that, its extension tells you the logo is locked.

```
World submorphs select: [ :m | 
    m class = ImageMorph and: [ 
    m isLocked not ] ] 
thenDo: [ :m | m delete ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, which is not so practical in this case, but is unique to smalltalk, is to use `#allInstances`. You can do

```
ImageMorph allInstances inspect
```

which returns all those images. in the raw view of the inspector, you can then send them `#delete`. Here that is not so practical, as the icons in the windows are also ImageMorphs, so you'll get a long list

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above I used Playground to inspect the World subMorphs.  This allows you to identify the unwanted images.
I then used (work SubMorphs at: n) delete to remove them individually.  You need to track the indices as they may change each time an image is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

To find all messages an object will understand, have a look at its class **and at its superclasses**. You will find `delete` in the `Morph` class, a superclass of `ImageMorph`.

Try executing this line by line:

```
| url email morph |
email := 'stephane.ducasse@inria.fr'.
url := 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/', (MD5 hashMessage: email) hex asString , '.jpg'.
morph := (ZnEasy getJpeg: url) asMorph.
morph openInHand.
morph delete.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think this procedure only applies to the current morph. If several morphs were created without sending delete at the end, I think it will not possible to use delete this way afterwards.